# Jquery var usage

Tags: jquery

Can someone point me out what I am doing wrong? I can't get this work.

What it should do is fetch the content of a LI button = its name (for ezample if the list button displays "start"), and assign it to a variable. 
Then it should be used as input to fetch data from a file, but since there are multiple files to chose from I want to use a variable in the file name so I just got 1 listener for multiple list buttons

```
$PageRequest = 'empty';

$(window).load(function() {

$('.navbars').on("click", "li", "#navbut", function(event){
    $PageRequest = ( $( this ).text() ); // until here it works//
    var $content = .load(+$PageRequest+'.txt');             //get content
        $('#PaginaContent').html($content); //Set output element html        
      } 
});
```

Comment: Which part isn't working?

Comment: do you mean `$('#PaginaContent').load($PageRequest+'.txt')`?

Comment: what does this have to do with vars?

Comment: i think additional + in front of $PageRequest in line  var $content = .load(+$PageRequest+'.txt');  creating issue

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here:

```
.load(+$PageRequest+'.txt');
//----^ no plus symbol here
```

**Solution**

```
$PageRequest = $( this ).text();                // No need of extra parenthesis.
.load($PageRequest+'.txt');                     // Remove the + symbol in the front.
```

Comment: im getting an unexpected token at : var $content = .load(+$PageRequest+'.txt');

Comment: Remove the `+` please.

Comment: ok now getting load isnt deffined, ill have to skipp this all until after work :( thanks anyways

Comment: @WilcovanRossum Did you include `jquery.js`?